# Permission denial -> requires oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE but it's already on the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-securityexception, oppo

I can't open intents in oppo devices.
I've put required permissions on manifest `<uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE"/>` but never works... always show the same error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.coloros.safecenter/.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity mCallingUid=10222 } from ProcessRecord{6f75382 3122:com.test.myapp.debug/u0a222} (pid=3122, uid=10222) requires oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE
```

I've try all of this intents:

```
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oppo.safe", "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startupmanager.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safe", "com.coloros.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safe", "com.coloros.safe.permission.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safe", "com.coloros.safe.permission.startupmanager.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startsettings")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startupapp.startupmanager")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startupmanager.startupActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.startupapp.startupmanager")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.StartupAppListActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.privacypermissionsentry.PermissionTopActivity.Startupmanager")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.privacypermissionsentry.PermissionTopActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf", "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerUsageModelActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf", "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerSaverModeActivity")),
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf", "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerConsumptionActivity"))
```

Anyone know how to require oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE permission in my app?

Thank's for any help :)

Comment: Julia Soler i m also facing same issue